# Unsure if my ER Diagram to relational model is correct

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, relational-model

Ok, I'm brand new to SQL etc so apologies if this is totally wrong..

I have designed an ER Model which I feel is right and I am trying to convert it to relational model and want any advice as to where I am gone wrong on converting it or any tips. Racking my brain.

As I believe it..

**1-1 relationships**
entities are either combined or the primary key of one entity type is placed as a foreign key in the other relation.

**1-m relationships**
    The primary key from the `one side' is placed as a foreign key in the many side.

**m-n relationships**
    A new relation is created with the primary keys from each entity forming a composite key.

**multivalue attributes**
     a new table is created, primary key used from 1st table and attribute used in the second table alognside primary key.

So here's my go at Relational model, PK in bold, FK in italics

USER:
**USERID**  FNAME   LNAME   USERNAME    PASSWORD    USERTYPE    EMAIL

CUSTOMER:
**USERID**, *CUST_ID*, BIO

ADMIN:
**USERID** *ADMIN_ID*

ARTIST
**USERID**, *ARTIST_ID*,    BIO *REC_ID*

PRODUCER:
**PROD_ID**, Name, Email

RECORD LABEL:
**RECORD_ID** , NAME, DESCRIPTION

ALBUM:
**ALBUMID** NAME , COST, TITLE, NOOFSONGS

TRACK:
**TRACK ID**, NAME, COST, TITLE,  DESCRIPTION

TRACK REVIEW: DEPENDENT on TRACK SO TRACK ID comes into this table = 
**REVIEW_ID(PK)**, *TRK_ID(PK)* NAME

TRACK PURCHASE TABLE (USER id comes into this table as foreign key)
**TrackPuchaseID** *user_id*, date

ALBUM PURCHASE TABLE
**AlbumPuchaseID** *user_id*, date, quantity

GENRE TABLE?:
Not sure??

BPM: is mutli value atribute so becoems seperate table so it.s
**GenreID** BPM

I know this all might be wrong. but any help would be great..  with explanation which should be FK or composite PK etc or what tables I am missing..

Comment: Just out of curiosity may I ask why you decided to create different entities for `User` and `Customer`?

Comment: I'm learning and thought this would be best option become familiar with er and relation model.. How would you have set yours or advise?

Comment: Anything I would say would be subjectable.  Also you might have business rules you need to enforce.  You made a good diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On `album purchase` you should have: `user_id`, `date`, `album_id`.
- At `track purchase` I don't see why you care about the `quantity` and
  you're missing the `track_id`.
- `review`, `track`, `album`, `user` should all include a `date`. Might
  be as well interesting to add an `last_update_date` to the `artist`
  and `customer`.
- `review` should include an `user_id`.

I guess there's other thing left. You will need an `Invoice` / `Invoice_Purchase` table to be able to say "customer xyz bought the items 1,2,3,4...", it should be like:

Table `Invoice`

- invoice_id
- user_id
- date
- status

Table `Invoice_Purchase`

- invoice_id // Id of the invoice
- purchase_type // the type of the purchase (for eg. 0 means track and 1 means album)

Maybe you should also add a `status` to your albuns and tracks, this way you can set if a item can be bought or not. And yes, you shouldn't delete them because you'll have the old invoices relaying on it...

Anyways, you should consider <s>later</s> using a software like `Navicat` do draw the relation part and deploy your DB.

Comment: Thank you.. I see in the ER diagram it is wrong but do you mean in relation table only? what should be in album purchase in relation table... 

Track Purchase, I see what you mean, I'll alter that. 

I'll include a date in what you mentioned.. S

I'll add user Id to review.. 

So after that I am not missing any tables and all the foreign keys are there? 

Just downloaded trial of Navicat, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: edit* 
I am not putting in any foreginkeys in my ER Diagram.. I want to put all main entities, relationships and attributes in the ER diagram, and put in the foregin keys in relation table once done with the ER diagram

Comment: @Michael_P you're following an academic approach to this, I guess... and you're falling into the "premature optimization category". From my point of view your DB is more than enough to start coding today. ;) The only table you're missing is the `Invoice` one, that tracks who bought what, and the payment status. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, yeah that's it. If i was to put in an invoice table in ER diagram as I am working on it, Where would I add it?
That is without foreign keys now,because as I said I will be putting them in on relational table. 
I'll answer as correct in a moment just would like to see how to do the invoice.

Comment: Please check my edit, you need two tables if you consider the relation between the invoice and the purchases...

Comment: Many thanks, I clicked the tick, doe that mean I gave you the correct answer.

Comment: Don't forget you can't remove tracks or albums or change their prices, because if you do that, it will have an impact on all the exiting invoices. The best way is to just create a new product and disable the old one using the status. This way you get a revision system as bonus !

Answer (score 0):

From an initial look, here are some of my impressions, in no particular order.

- **1-1 relationships:** not only is the PK of the entity defined as a FK in the related table, it is also the related table's PK. This preserves the unity of the relationship.
- **multivalue attributes:** in other words, a 1-m relationship.
- There is no reason to have separate ID values for Customer, Admin or Artist. In fact, call them all ID. I would say this is a m-1 relationship as a user could be both a customer and an artist. But the relationship between User table and the others individually are 1-1.
- Isn't Track related to Album? So wouldn't AlbumID be a Track attribute?
- Purchase tables should have CustID not UserID and be FK to Customer table. This enforces the need that a purchaser be defined as a customer.
- Genre could be an attribute of track or album or both. An album could be generally "Country" but have a "Blues" track, a "Pop" track, etc.
- Same for producer. There will be an album producer but could be one or more tracks produced by someone else.
- Same for artist. There may be one artist for the entire album but what about "The Greatest Top 40 Hits of the 1980s"?
- You may want an intersection table between Artist and Label. A label can sign up many artists and an artist could work for many labels (though generally not at the same time).
- I have no idea what a BPM is.

That should keep you busy for a while.